# YouTube Data API Quota Extension Application -- is Captcha broken?

Tags: youtube-data-api, quota

At the bottom of the Youtube Data API Quota Extension Application, this is what I see. Has anyone had this same experience and, if so, is there a workaround?:
[image: At the bottom of the Youtube Data API Quota Extension Application, this is what I see. Has anyone had this same experience and, if so, is there a workaround?]

Comment: Added to Google Issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79183616

Comment: Come on Google.  The Quota Extension Application form is broken and has been for six weeks.  Please fix it or suggest another process for requesting quota extension.

Comment: 2.5 months and counting.  Is Youtube engineering really monitoring stack overflow? Quota Extensions is broken, please fix.